# Lost access to permissions checkboxes at admin/config/group/permissions/node/<group>

Tags: organic-groups

Not sure what happened. I'm using Drupal 7.15 and the latest OG dev version (2.x) and for some reason, I lost access to all permissions checkboxes at admin/config/group/permissions/node/ - It's not even showing them in read-only mode, they are just not there.

I do have OG access control and field access modules enabled and I haven't done much but trying to create a new group and new content.

Rebuilding permissions or uninstalling the modules completely didn't help.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a corresponding bug: http://drupal.org/node/1649186